# I cannot install mysql on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to install mysql-server on my ubuntu 18.04 ,but I am getting the dpkg error

The terminal output after `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` is

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done The following additional packages will be
>   installed:   libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 mysql-client-5.7
>   mysql-client-core-5.7   mysql-common mysql-server-5.7
>   mysql-server-core-5.7 Suggested packages:   mailx tinyca The following
>   NEW packages will be installed:   libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6
>   mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7   mysql-common mysql-server
>   mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 0 upgraded, 8 newly installed,
>   0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B/19.1 MB of archives.
>   After this operation, 155 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do
>   you want to continue? [Y/n] Y Preconfiguring packages ... Selecting
>   previously unselected package mysql-common. (Reading database ...
>   274343 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
>   .../0-mysql-common_1%3a10.4.12+maria~eoan_all.deb ... Unpacking
>   mysql-common (1:10.4.12+maria~eoan) ... Selecting previously
>   unselected package libaio1:amd64. Preparing to unpack
>   .../1-libaio1_0.3.110-5ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking libaio1:amd64
>   (0.3.110-5ubuntu0.1) ... Selecting previously unselected package
>   mysql-client-core-5.7. Preparing to unpack
>   .../2-mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7. Preparing to
>   unpack .../3-mysql-client-5.7_5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ... Selecting
>   previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7. Preparing to
>   unpack .../4-mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
>   ... Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.1-6:amd64.
>   Preparing to unpack
>   .../5-libevent-core-2.1-6_2.1.8-stable-4build1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
>   libevent-core-2.1-6:amd64 (2.1.8-stable-4build1) ... Setting up
>   mysql-common (1:10.4.12+maria~eoan) ... Selecting previously
>   unselected package mysql-server-5.7. (Reading database ... 274503
>   files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
>   .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
>   mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ... Selecting previously
>   unselected package mysql-server. Preparing to unpack
>   .../mysql-server_5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ... Unpacking
>   mysql-server (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ... Setting up
>   libevent-core-2.1-6:amd64 (2.1.8-stable-4build1) ... Setting up
>   libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-5ubuntu0.1) ... Setting up
>   mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ... Setting up
>   mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ... Setting up
>   mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ... Setting up
>   mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
>   /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 191:
>   /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
>   dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure): 
>   installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess
>   returned error exit status 127 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
>   configuration of mysql-server:  mysql-server depends on
>   mysql-server-5.7; however:   Package mysql-server-5.7 is not
>   configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the
>   error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
>                             Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.39)
>   ... Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ... Processing
>   triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ... ureadahead will be reprofiled
>   on next reboot Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   mysql-server-5.7  mysql-server E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned
>   an error code (1)

I have tried every other solution that I could find on stack overflow and elsewhere on the Internet.

The solutions that i have tried include `purging mysql`,`autoremove`,`autoclean`,`dist upgrade`,`reboot`,`removing /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql` and almost every other thing that I could find related to this problem.It is not helping me, and now asking this question because no other answers were helping me.I am not worried of losing any DB that I might I have on my system.

I must add that since installing mysql was not working for me,I went with mongodb.It installed fine initally ,but now even removing and installing mongodb is givinf the same Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the following steps,

1.) First, update the apt package index by typing:

```
$sudo apt update
```

2.)Then install the MySQL package with the following command:

```
$sudo apt install mysql-server
```

3.)Once the installation is completed, the MySQL service will start automatically. To check whether the MySQL server is running, type:

```
$sudo systemctl status mysql
```

output
●

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-2-20 11:30:23 PDT; 5min ago
 Main PID: 17382 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 27 (limit: 2321)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           `-17382 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.Unfortunately I still getting the same dpkg error

Comment: @MaitrayaKakade try to uninstall all the refrences and do a fresh install once again.

Comment: How do find all the references? I have already removed mysql directory from etc and lib.I have removed cnf files and tried installing but it still gives me the same error.I think purging mysql is not removing all the packages.

Comment: do this,   $ dpkg --list|grep -i mysql  and follow the steps as described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/   hope this will help

Comment: Thanks .This worked out for me.If possible can you please explain why I was facing this problem?

Comment: @MaitrayaKakade it seems you probably had broken some dependencies. Could you please upvote the answer as it helped you :)